# LocalStorage - Add a class on a clicked div tutorial

Tags: jquery

I have two divs and I need to add a class to one of them when the user click it, and I need to use LocalStorage to keep the class on the same div when the user open the page again.

I didnt find any tutorial. Do you guys know any tutorial or example how can i build it? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#divName').on('click', function(){
window.localStorage.setItem('dados',$("#divName").addClass('borda'));

});
if(localStorage.getItem('dados')){
    $("#divName").addClass('borda');
}
})
```

It worked for me. Thank you guys :)

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on HTML5 local storage. Surely you've heard of [Google](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=html5+local+storage)

Comment: most of them are about "to-do-list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to insert something on localstorage on click :

```
$('#yourDiv').on('click', function(){

    window.localStorage.setItem( 'your key name', 'your classname' );

});
```

And then when the user opens the page again, heres the code to retreive your key on the local storage:

```
var className = JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem( 'your key name' ) );
$('#yourDiv').addClass(className);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot cal method 'insert' of undefined

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. the method is "setItem" and not insert.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as user click on one div store its class in localstorage.

You can do that by setting up the class name for the very first time as below

```
localStorage.clasondiv1 = "classname";
```

Also on window.load or jquery.ready(if using jquery) you can check for whether the class exists in localstorage if yes then set the class on div.

you can use **store.js** which provides a wrapper over localStorage.

```
https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js
```

Comment: i tried it in many ways but im really beginner on Jquery, so i failed.

Comment: jQuery is not that tough, just google for some easy jQuery tutorials, I am sure you will be able to get through jQuery basics in few hours.